# Select option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm in the middle of a problem here.

I have a Ajax script that returns this "Rua Américo Vezzani@Park Aliança@Matão@SP", then I split this result and match with the options of a select tag

```
      function (retorno)
        {
            var array_retorno = retorno.split('@');
            $(".endereco_load").val(array_retorno[0]);
            $(".bairro_load").val(array_retorno[1]);
            $(".cidade_load").val(array_retorno[2]);

            var estado = array_retorno[3].toString() ;

           $(".estado_load ").find('option').each(function() {
               if( $(this).val().match(estado)  ) {
                    $(this).attr({ selected : "selected" });
                }
           });

           // $(".estado_load option[value='" + estado + "']").attr({ selected : "selected" });

        },
```

the problem is that the code above doesnt work.

when i set my variable estado like this for instance

```
var estado = 'SP';
```

it works

can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide your HTML or a JSFiddle demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't name your function and .toString isn't necessary.

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/13s58xjj/

```
function splitString(retorno)
     {
        var array_retorno = retorno.split('@');
        $(".endereco_load").val(array_retorno[0]);
        $(".bairro_load").val(array_retorno[1]);
        $(".cidade_load").val(array_retorno[2]);

        var estado = array_retorno[3];
        alert(estado);
       $(".estado_load ").find('option').each(function() {
           if( $(this).val().match(estado)  ) {
                $(this).attr({ selected : "selected" });
            }
       });
```

You can remove the alert, I left it in for debugging

Comment: it still dont work, only if i set my estado variable directly, like this var estado = "SP", getting the data from the array does not work

Comment: Can you post your html or fork the fiddle and add it

Comment: I don't see your HTML still.. but try an === instead of match http://jsfiddle.net/13s58xjj/4/

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
   $(".estado_load ").find('option').each(function() {
       if( $(this).val().match(estado)  ) {
            $(this).attr({ selected : "selected" });
        }
   });
```

To:

```
$(".estado_load option").filter(function() {
    return this.value.trim() == estado.trim();
})
.attr('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to `trim` like this:

```
 if( $(this).val().trim().match(estado.trim())) {
      // all stuff here
 }
```

Working [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/13s58xjj/6/)